# rule of 5 with gmock test interface?

Tags: c++

From the Mocking for Dummies page:
https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html#a-case-for-mock-turtles

I would define an testable interface like this:

```cpp
class Turtle {
  ...
  virtual ~Turtle() {}
  ...
```

My linter is screaming at me that I should follow the rule of 3.
So I added:

```cpp
  Turtle() = default;
  Turtle(const Turtle& x) = default;
  Turtle& operator=(const Turtle& x) = default;
```

And then it still complained that I need move constructor and assignment operator so I had to add:

```cpp
  Turtle(Turtle&& x) = default;
  Turtle& operator=(Turtle&& x) = default;
```

Alright, so I recognize that this is rule of 5.

And then, for each class that I inherit from this interface, I have to do the same thing  i.e. a destructor plus 5 default constructors/assignment operators.

My questions are:

1. Am I doing it correctly?
2. Is it really necessary to put so much boilerplate?

Comment: I wonder if `virtual ~Turtle() = default;` would calm whatever linter you are using.  That change would mean it is no longer _user defined_, and shouldn't be subject to the rule of 5.

Comment: It didn't... if I remember correctly. I'm just wondering what's the best practice.

Comment: If you ask a human, the best practice is to assume that `virtual ~Turtle() = default;` has no bearing on the rule of 5.  Are you asking what to do when good practices conflict with the output of a linter?

Comment: What linter are you using? What version of it? Perhaps it's configured to be a little too paranoid, because if `virtual ~Turtle() = default;` is enough for your class (which it seems to be) then that's alright.

Comment: _"Is it really necessary to put so much boilerplate?"_  Just to directly answer your question... No.  Not unless your organization demands that linter messages be addressed.  Linters can be _very good_ at giving advice that is bad.

Comment: Confirmed. Using `default` still does not satisfy the linter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @DrewDormann It's clang-tidy https://releases.llvm.org/13.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-special-member-functions.html

I guess I'm using the default options today, or otherwise it can be customized with the `AllowSoleDefaultDtor` option.

Comment: @fatdragon if your last comment means that your question is answered, please feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using clangtidy https://releases.llvm.org/13.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-special-member-functions.html

If I define the destructor as `default`

```
virtual ~Turtle() = default;
```

Then I can at least customized the linter behavior with the `AllowSoleDefaultDtor` option.